# The TypeError: this.each when wp.media.open() after using popper.js for bootstrap 4

Tags: errors

I'm creating page metabox layout through bootsrap 4 framework. I added to admin enqueue the new js files: jquery-3.0.0, jquery-migrate-3.0.1 as well as popper-1.12.3 and bootstrap. Also the custom field was created in metabox. I get a image link used admin media modal frame. I mean the frame used jQuery  to get wp.media object, but after additing popper.js the wp.media.open() function got the Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function in some files.
[image]
[image]
May someone fix this issue?

Comment: Check if the problem occurs with the wp core version of jQuery, temporarily comment out the deregister scripts and see if this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem through correction of the jQuery code.
This is an example

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
// Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
var file_frame, meta_image_preview, meta_image;
$('.image-upload').on('click', function( event ){

    meta_image_preview = $(this).parent().parent().children('.image-preview');
    meta_image = $(this).parent().children('.meta-image');
    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( file_frame ) {
        // Open frame
        file_frame.open();
        return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select a image to upload',
        button: {
            text: 'Use this image',
        },
        multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on( 'select', function() {

        // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
        media_attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
        meta_image.val(media_attachment.url);
        meta_image_preview.children('img').attr('src', media_attachment.url);
    });
        // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();

});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="image-section">
    <p>
        <label for="section-image">Image Upload</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="meta[image]" id="section-image" class="meta-image regular-text" value="<?php echo isset($meta['image']) ? $meta['image']: ''; ?>">
        <input type="button" class="button image-upload" value="Browse">
    </p>

    <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="<?php echo isset($meta['image']) ? $meta['image'] : ''; ?>" style="max-width: 250px;">
    </div>
</div>
```